# Legal operation in limit summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, power-series, exponential-function

I'm evaluating the following function

$$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}{e^{-b(t-1)}(1-e^{-b})(1-\rho)^t}$$

I attempted to solve it by equating it to

$$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}{e^{-b(t-1)}}(1-e^{-b})\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}(1-\rho)^t$$
$$=\frac{e^b}{e^b-1}(1-e^{-b})\frac{1-\rho}{\rho}$$
$$=\frac{1-\rho}{\rho}$$

However, different results from the numerical calculation of the original summation function suggests that this is not a legal operation. Is that correct?

Comment: "Is that correct?" No, since in general, $$\sum_t a_tb_t\ne\sum_ta_t\times\sum_tb_t.$$ To compute your sum, note that it is $$e^b(1-e^{-b})\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}[e^{-b}(1-\rho)]^t.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series is convergent as soon as $|1-\rho|<e^b$ and it is equal to
$$e^b(1-e^{-b})\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}[e^{-b}(1-\rho)]^t=(e^b-1)\cdot \frac{e^{-b}(1-\rho)}{1-e^{-b}(1-\rho)}=\frac{(e^b-1)(1-\rho)}{e^b-(1-\rho)}.$$